# scala funtion apply of object in different file not work

Tags: scala

when I put the object `Square` and the call `Square(20)` in the same files. It runs:

```
object TestDSL extends App {
    object Square {
        def apply(x: Int) = {
            System.out.println("square " + x)
        }
    }

    Square(20)
}
```

However when I put the Square object into another class. Here is main.scala. When I import jung.Square, I got the errror : "object Square is not a member of package"

```
import jung.Square
object TestDSL extends App {
    Square(20)
}
```

Here is Square file:

```
object Square {
    def apply(x: Int) = {
        System.out.println("square " + x)
    }
}
```

I dont really know why.

Comment: What is the error? Is the package correctly named in both files?

Comment: Just tried this out and it worked fine. How are you trying to run this?